# check all checkboxes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
if $('#myDiv').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

Unchecks all checkboxes is there a line of code that will add the check to all of the checkboxes without looping each checkbox?

I've tried:

`$('#myDiv' input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))`;

But that did not work. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Well you have a typo in your selector...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NogginBox/ScnQT/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

### jQuery 1.6+

```
$('#myDiv input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

### jQuery 1.5.x and below

```
$('#myDiv input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

Note: `$( ":checkbox" )` is equivalent to `$( "[type=checkbox]" )`

Comment: Works great  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $('#myDiv input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
```

As per the accepted answer this only works for jquery 1.5.x and below.